# Android app closes when clicking on 'arqade' when viewing a question

Tags: bug, android-app

I was viewing an [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) question on the Android app, and I wanted to go back to the list of latest questions, so I pressed on where it says 'arqade' on the lefthand side. As soon as I did, the app crashed on me and forcefully closed. It happens every time, and the only way I can go back is to press the back arrow on my tablet itself.

- Prestigio multipad 4 diamond
- Android version 4.4
- Latest version of the app

Comment: Note: "latest version" is assumed as v1.0.71 as of current writing. It'd be clearer if you specify the version. You can check the version by going to "About" from the sidebar menu. Also, does it happen on other sites/questions?

Comment: Yes it happens on them all.